# JSON like syntax vs switch statement javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I saw a post on http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/shorthand-javascript-techniques/ where he talks about an alternative way to using switch statements.

I have created a snippet below, but I'm not sure why the alternate is 99% slow.

```
function doX(){}
function doY(){}
function doN(){}
var something = 1;

var cases = {
    1: doX,
    2: doY,
    3: doN
};
if (cases[something]) {
    cases[something]();
}
```

http://jsperf.com/alternateswitch

Any idea?

Comment: Just like the shorthand version of if/else he is talking about, it is shorter, but it isn't faster at all.

Comment: That "JSON" syntax is just an object.

Comment: I also think a large part of your difference in results is a misuse of jsperf. Make sure to add any one time code to the setup portion of the tests. Here is an example using your code: http://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/3

Comment: Note that not all switch patterns translate easily (if you omit the break statement in a switch, execution falls through to the next case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author never claimed the shorter code, which is just a hash map of the possible cases,  would actually be faster. Obviously, the array creation negatively impacts the performance when you run it in a test suite. At the same time, the `switch` statement is compiled code.

You will see some improvement if your code is being reused, i.e. you keep the value of `cases`; I've measured a difference of about 20-30% in [this test case](http://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/4), depending on which case occurs more often.

That said, an isolated performance test such as this won't be useful unless your code is run inside a tight loop, because the test cases run at 50M+ operations per second on my home computer. Differences between the two should therefore be based on other factors, such as code clarity or the fact that `switch` statements are easy to mess up if you forget to place `break;` a statement.

Comment: Your test case is unfair. You are doing the associative array look up twice.

Comment: @invisal It's the original code and without the extra lookup the code  strictly isn't the same as a `switch`.

Answer (score 8):

That "JSON" syntax is just an object. Also, your comparison is a little unfair here, as you create a brand new object every single timed loop, which is somewhat expensive.

If you move the object creation to the setup section, the speed difference becomes neglibile: http://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/4

If you remove the `if` statement, the object will be a tad faster (at least for me): http://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/5. The extra property lookup and truthiness check does slow it down.

Answer (score 3):

- I believe that Javascript object is an associative array which
  usually implemented as a hash table. Each lookup requires a key to go
  through a hashing function. Hashing function is like a double blade. For a small size data, it would be slower than a if-elseif-else. However, for larger data, it will outperform ordinary if-elseif-else
- It is very unfair that you are favoring the `switch`, you make that the variable you are looking for is at the first case. Therefore, the complexity for `switch` is O(1) for your testing.

Comment: Huh, I never would've guessed that the order of the cases in the switch statement actually has a significant performance impact: http://jsperf.com/alternateswitch/8

Comment: @Jack, if you have N cases, the complexity of the switch is not always O(1). I believe that `switch` in Javascript is implemented similarly to if-else, not as a jump-table.

Comment: Okay, if you express the statement as a chain of N conditions, the running cost is always O(N).

Comment: @Jack, the reason that I think implementation of `switch` is a chain of N condition is because of that `switch` in Javascript even support string. It is not possible to do jump-table ([Branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table)).

Answer (score 1):

Usually `switch` statements are optimized by the compiler/interpreter. They are even faster than chained `if-else` statements. By using a `JSON` object instead of `switch` statement, you're bypassing the Javascript engine optimization.